# Jersey - Obtain the contents of an OutputStream in an Interceptor before calling context.proceed()

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0

Using an Interceptor in Jersey I can manipulate the Output, however, I also want to add a Header to the response which value is calculated from the result of the output.

```
@Sha256Sum
public class Sha256SumInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {

    public static final String SHA256_HASH_HEADER_NAME = "SHA256-SUM";

    @Override
    public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        // Retrieve the OutputStream, read the contents and calculate the hashsum.
        // Set the header value in context.
        context.proceed();
    }
}
```

However, the issue is that when I finally have read the entire stream, I'm unable to set the headers as when context.proceed is called and the contents written (and thus enabling me to do anything with it) I can no longer set the header.

My question in short: How do I capture the entire stream output as a byte[], calculate a result from the array of bytes and finally set the header in the response to the computed result? I do not want to deplete the output stream.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you've ever worked with an AOP framework or even CDI interceptors, you'll have worked with the concept of Around-Advice or Around-Invoke, respectively. You can perform operations before *and* after the invocation of the advised/intercepted method. `context.proceed()` works the same way; it's the method invocation (or more precisely the `MessageBodyWriter` doing it's writing). We can perform some operations before the `MessageBodyWriter` does it's job, call `proceed()` to let the writer do it's work, then we can do some more work.

With that said, here are the steps you can take:

1. Hold onto the old `OutputStream` from the `context`, with `context.getOutputStream()`
2. Create a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and set that as the `OutputStream` on the context, with `context.setOutputStream(baos)`
3. Call `context.proceed()`. What this does is have the `MessageBodyWriter` write to the `ByteArrayOutputStream`.
4. Get the `byte[]` from the `ByteArrayOutputStream` with `baos.toByteArray()`
5. Checksum the `byte[]` and set the header
6. Write the `byte[]` to the old `OutputStream`.
7. Finally set the `OutputStream` on the `context` to the old `OutputStream`.

Here's the basic implementation (tested and works as expected)

```
@Provider
public class ChecksumInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        OutputStream old = context.getOutputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {

            context.setOutputStream(buffer);
            // let MessageBodyWriter do it's job
            context.proceed();

            // get bytes
            byte[] entity = buffer.toByteArray();

            String checksum = ChecksumUtil.createChecksum(entity);
            context.getHeaders().putSingle("X-Checksum", checksum);

            old.write(entity);
        } finally {
            context.setOutputStream(old);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks neat, but what if the `ChecksumUtil` also needs access to the client request method and URI info? `WriterInterceptorContext` does not provide them.