# Stream provider is not defined. It must be set before writing first bytes to the entity output stream

Tags: rest, jersey, servlet-filters, outputstream

I am trying to modify my all response's.
To achieve that i am using jerseys ContainerResponseFilter.
however i am getting this exception

"**Stream provider is not defined. It must be set before writing first bytes to the entity output stream.text**"

outputstream provider is provided by ContainerResponseContext.
What am i supposed to set??

Sample:---

```
public class FilterResp implements ContainerResponseFilter {
@Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext arg0, ContainerResponseContext responsecotext) throws IOException {
        OutputStream entityStream = responsecotext.getEntityStream();
        responsecotext.setEntityStream(entityStream);
        entityStream.write("gfgfgf".getBytes());
        entityStream.flush();

    }
```

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] in context with path [/PspServices] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Stream provider is not defined. It must be set before writing first bytes to the entity output stream.] with root cause
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Stream provider is not defined. It must be set before writing first bytes to the entity output stream.
>       at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:149)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:200)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:195)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutputStream.java:229)

Comment: Use [`WriterInterceptor`](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9505) to alter the body.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha yes had to that way, is there any out of the box utility by jersey with which I can sign the xml.

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33519702/2587435)?